# How to install additional languages to app platform?

Tags: heroku, devops, digital-ocean

I have a Django project for which I use a french locale for some dates and functions, I am deploying using Digital Ocean App Plateform which use Heroku for the build pack, I cannot figure out how to add a new language to my server.

I have tried the following :

- sudo apt-get install language-support-fr # Does not work as I don't have sudo rights
- Adding a .locales to my app root project with the language code # Does not work

I do not find anything in the documentation nor StackOverflow, thank you